# mongoDB insert_many accepts a list of dict but update_many does not

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to update a mongoDB collection using update_many. I have a list of dict which I am trying to insert into a collection. While I am able to use insert_many() to insert this list of dict, when I am using update_many() to update, it gives me the following error.

TypeError: update must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping

My data is in following format

record1 =  [{'symbol': 'A', 'volume': 359}, {'symbol': 'A', 'volume': 387}]

record2 =  [{'symbol': 'A', 'volume': 964}, {'symbol': 'A', 'volume': 982}]

when I do **db.table.insert_many(record1)** it works perfectly.
Now I am trying to replace the contents of the table with this :
**db.table.update_many({}, record1, upsert=True)**

I get : TypeError: update must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping

Comment: Can you at least show the salient details i.e. the code which is calling the `update_many()` method and the documents you are passing as arguments to the method.

Comment: Please add relevant code in your question

Comment: This is what you want: [Updating database from a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36562527/890558)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this :

```
db.table.update_many({}, {"$set":record1}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: You need to add some narrative that explains why your solution meets their needs.